# Algorithm: How to schedule/distribute hours within/from a weekly hour quota?

Tags: algorithm, date, math, time

If I have, say, 5days*(8hourWorkday-2hoursForUnexpectedWork) = 30 hours a week of time to use, how can I programmatically schedule tasks to fill that 30 hours?

For instance, I have 5 tasks, each of which I estimate will take the following amount of time:

```
#1:  2h
#2:  4h
#3:  6h
#4:  8h
#5: 10h
```

How would I sort that into say:

```
M: #1 @ 2h + #2 @ 4h
T: #3 @ 6h
W: #4 @ 6h
H: #4 @ 2h + #5 @ 4h
F: #5 @ 6h
```

In other words, how to account for 'iterated-sum container-overflows'?

Ultimately I also need to be able to account for tasks that overflow the week too, for instance, if the the previous example I had a task `#6: 40h` (itself 10h more than the week, and bringing the weekly sum to 40h extra that would need to spill into the previous two weeks).

## EDIT:

A second, more complicated example, again with 5 tasks, this time with (optional) day of week requirements:

```
#1:  2h, W[0][M]
#2:  4h, W[0][T]
#3:  6h, W[0][M]
#4:  8h, W[0][F]
#5: 40h, W[0][F]
```

How would I sort this to, say,

```
W[-1][M]: #5 @ 6h
W[-1][T]: #5 @ 6h
W[-1][W]: #5 @ 6h
W[-1][H]: #5 @ 6h
W[-1][F]: #3 @ 2h + #5 @ 4h
W[ 0][M]: #1 @ 2h + #3 @ 4h
W[ 0][T]: #2 @ 4h + #5 @ 2h
W[ 0][W]: #5 @ 6h
W[ 0][H]: #4 @ 2h + #5 @ 4h
W[ 0][F]: #4 @ 6h
```

[image: Illustration #1]

The best case scenario would actually be that #3 pushes #1 back a day as illustrated here:
[image: Illustration #2]

### Further Clarification:

- For each specified day of the week (MTWHF), fill up to 6 hours of time.
- If there is overflow, spill into the previous day(s).
- Ideally, this spill would happen in a Knapsack-or-similar-optimized fashion, so that the 6 hours would be filled as completely as possible by whole/unbroken tasks.
- Similarly, for days which are spilled into, they should adjust their spillage to be whole-task-unbreaking as well.

Comment: Just leaving the order the same, you want to break the work into 6-hour blocks?

Comment: I've added a second example.

Comment: You should list all of the possible requirements.  It sounds like you may not have fully explored the problem domain.

Comment: We need a characterization of a "feasible" solution for your problem and (if it is an optimization problem) the function to minimize/optimize.

Comment: Added, does this clarify enough?

Comment: If only more managers would ask this question.

Comment: Your requirement is still far too vague. If you 1) describe acceptable solutions clearly and 2) describe how to compute a single score for a solution, higher = better, then we can say more. As has been mentioned, the details can make this problem anything from trivially linear time to NP complete.  With what you've given so far, there's no way to tell where it lies.

Comment: Although I am not yet sure how exactly one can decide which solution is best (let alone which one is acceptable), I'd throw an idea out there - start by putting tasks >= 6h, but <= 12h at say, the beginning of the week, making sure that tasks equal to 6h or 12h don't get more than 1 or 2 days respectively. Perhaps you can also try grouping tasks that will fill up a precise number of days (say group 13h + 7h + 10h). But as @Gene stated you really need to clarify what is your goal in this.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, this seems like a solved problem. If tasks are assigned dynamically (as seems likely in a real-world environment), [earliest deadline first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling) scheduling can meet all deadlines provided that utlization remains manageable. Since jobs are only preempted when new jobs come in, this should result in low context-switching overhead and fairly good contiguity of work. It is a simple heuristic which has enjoyed some attention in the literature, so a lot of the guesswork is taken out of the equation.

EDIT: example.

```
#1:  2h, W[0][M]
#2:  4h, W[0][T]
#3:  6h, W[0][M]
#4:  8h, W[0][F]
#5: 40h, W[0][F]

EDF order: #1, #3, #2, #4, #5.

Schedule: 113333332222444444445555555555555555555555555555555555555555

In days: 113333 332222 444444 445555 555555 555555 555555 555555 555555 555555
```

Note that we could do better in terms of contiguity by taking this a-priori schedule and post-processing the results of EDF scheduling. Assuming that we have some context switch overhead when starting the day and whenever a number changes, this schedule yields 13 context switches, of which only 10 are obligatory. With the schedule #3, #1, #2, #4, #5, we get 12 context switches. I know that the question originally started out wanting to minimize the context switches. However, an optimal scheduling algorithm in that respect will only do better than EDF by hiding genuine context-switches in obligatory context-switches (that happen at the start of the day). EDF has the advantage of guaranteeing you always meet your deadlines, if meeting deadlines is possible. It's a tradeoff, but I think the nod goes to EDF.

Also consider [rate monotonic scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling) (taking as the period your deadlines) which may be more appropriate for statically-determined schedules, particularly if there is any regularity to the assigned tasks.

Comment: These are useful links, but the info here is incredibly dense for me. Mind unpacking it a bit and/or linking it to the example above?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). The wiki gives some solutions to this problem, but mostly this is solved with dynamic programming.

Comment: I don't think this is nearly as complicated as knapsack, since splitting tasks over multiple days apparently isn't a problem.

Comment: Ah I must've overlooked that, in that case it is indeed simpler. Just keep a counter of sorts until you run out.